# Converter "unsigned int" em vetor de "unsigned char"?

Tags: c, bitwise

Preciso converter um `unsigned int` em um vetor de `unsigned char` para posteriormente traduzir esses endereço em binário, para um trabalho que preciso simular uma memoria virtual. Alguém pode me explicar como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer reinterpretar um vetor de inteiros para um vetor de "bytes". Logo, você pode fazer isso aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ASIZE(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

int main (void) {

    const unsigned int teste[5] = {300, 500, 900, 1100, 1300};
    unsigned char *buf = NULL;
    size_t jmp = 0;

    buf = malloc(ASIZE(teste));
    if (!buf) abort();

    for (size_t index = 0; index < ASIZE(teste); index++,jmp+=sizeof(int)) {
            buf[jmp] = teste[index] & 0x000000ff;
            buf[jmp+1] = (teste[index] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            buf[jmp+2] = (teste[index] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            buf[jmp+3] = (teste[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            printf("%u - %u - %u - %u\n", buf[jmp+3], buf[jmp+2], buf[jmp+1], buf[jmp]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O código acima faz uso de manipulação em bits. Caso você não saiba o que é isso, basta dar uma olhadinha aqui: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators

Answer (score 1):

A resposta que você escolheu como melhor pode ser responsável por [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) isto é poderá alterar pedaços de memória que não lhe pertencem causando crashes ou bugs.
Se fosse eu a você utilizaria uma [union][2] para converter, mais fácil, rápido e viável.

Vejam o exemplo aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

   typedef union _Conversor
   {
       unsigned int inicial; //Valor que vai armazenar
       unsigned char leitor[4];//Para ler todos os bytes unsigned int tem 4 em windows e linux
    }Conversor;

    Conversor conv;
    conv.inicial = 0xCE87;//Valor random
    printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X\n", conv.leitor[0], conv.leitor[1], conv.leitor[2], conv.leitor[3]);


    return 0;   
}
```

http://ideone.com/58FMdE

Comment: Eu até gosto maus da idéia de usar union, mas não vi como a outra solução pode ter um comportamento indefinido.  Você pode explicar essa afirmação?

Comment: @prmottajr Eu testei e compilei o programa da outra solução funciona. Até printei o sizeof(buf) só para ter a certeza e deu-me 8. Sendo o tamanho de uma int normalmente 4, no for loop acaba por ultrapassar o limite do da string. 

Imagine que numa posição consecutiva tem outra string ou um int ou uma estrutura. Vai acabar por editá-la. 

Espero que tenha sido esclarecedor na minha resposta. Já agora qual é o problema com a union? Pode ser pouco usual mas é muito util neste tipo de operações

Comment: como eu disse eu gosto da abordagem do union. Talvez o priblema com a outra solução e que também afeta o union é que os tamanhos dos tipos de dados variam com a arquitetura da máquina. Acho que vale um sizeof(int) né?

Comment: @prmottajr Tem razão mas como acho que este programa não tem a intenção de ser portado para mais SO pode-se usar INT. Mesmo assim tem razão o tamanho de int varia de consoante a arquitetura da máquina, por isso um bom programador deve usar o header `inttypes.h` que contem int8_t, int16_t e muito mais. Sendo assim o seu tamanho não varia.

Comment: Mas independente do SO mudar (linux, windows ou mac os) entre 32 e 64 bits de arquitetura também varia.

Comment: @prmottajr [Vendo aqui] Segundo isto ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models ) o tamanho do int não varia de 32 bits para 64 bits no caso do windows.

Comment: +1 pela referência, foi um bom debate. Já tive muitos problemas com long e ponteiros. Acabei assumindo o mesmo para int

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente qualquer coisa como isto

```
unsigned int valor = 1042;
unsigned char vetor[38]; // escolher limite apropriado
int len = snprintf(vetor, sizeof vetor, "%u", valor);
// vetor 'e a string "1042", ou seja
// vetor[0] == '1'; vetor[1] = '0'; vetor[2] = '4'; vetor[3] = '2'; vetor[4] = '\0';
```

Se quiseres converter para valores em vez de caracteres, diminui `'0'` a cada caracter

```
for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) vetor[k] -= '0'; // vetor ja nao 'e uma string!
// vetor[0] == 1; vetor[1] = 0; vetor[2] = 4; vetor[3] = 2;
```

Comment: Neste caso eu só estarei printando o unsigned int como um unsigned char, eu preciso converter e salva-lo em uma variavel.